# NUMA effects on single-process inference

Tags: pytorch

I've been reading [this article](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchserve_with_ipex.html), which explains some of the effects of a multi-cpu, hyperthreaded system and suggests ways to get around the issues. Namely: put each problem domain on its own socket; that is, if I'm running a model, then run a copy of the model on each socket.

However, what if my use-case is a LLM/transformer outputting text. Just inference, no training. Due to the sequential nature of the process, the essential effect of applying the "optimizations" there is to run on one socket, and ignore the rest of the machine.

There's only one batch, and only one worker, so the server, on an 8-socket system, would be 88% idle.

I'm interested in what it would take to run on all the numa nodes simultaneously. Assuming no specific optimizations save perhaps avoiding hyperthreaded cores, where would performance end up at on a typical multi-socket system? The reason to do so is that 3-5 year old servers can be had with 10x the memory of new GPU based systems for 1/10th the price, with chips for as little as 2% of their original prices. And I'm wondering if there would be any benefit of a many-socket system over say a 1-socket or 2-socket one, for the throughput of a single, albeit very large, model.

Basically, comparing eight Xeon 8180Ms to say a single epyc rome 7702P. Which would 'win' at this task?

The interesting part is that model weights, during inference, *do not change*. So, I have this huge chunk of data which is being read by the processors. So if this is cached locally, if that matters, could lead to what should be close to linear performance scaling.

If I add more memory than the model needs; say 192GB per socket for a 120GB model (30B parameters @ fp32/AVX), would pytorch know 'out of the box' that it could cache using the extra memory to keep all accesses of the model weights local? Or is there some [numactl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl) command for this?

What happens if the model is too big for the memory of one socket, but still much smaller than the memory in the system?